# android app crashes after upgrading Constraint layout from 1.1.2 to 1.1.3

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, system-error

App was working fine before upgrading from 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2' to 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

I got no line error just this system error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.getTargetWidget(ConstraintLayout.java:1144)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:1028)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:803)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1561)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24973)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
    at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24973)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24973)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1059)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24973)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7139)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: Crash probably is not related to upgrade you made instead it is related to changes you made inside XML code or Java code. Exception says that somewhere inside your code you are trying to use `LayoutParams` of `FrameLayout` instead of `ConstraintLayout`
`android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: I found the solution. I had added this line incorrectly in my View "slideLayer:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraint_layout" which was not a sibling in the same layout. Thanks for trying to help me